# How to use Visual studio designer to setup data bindings in winforms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, designer, bindingsource

We are creating a winforms application. We want to use the Visual studio UI to setup the data bindings at design time.  By this I mean, we want to be able to define at design time, what datasource and property a textbox or checkbox or any other control should use.

We put a DataSet on the form.  This dataset will be populated at run time.
We put a BindingSource on the form and set its DataSource to the DataSet.
We put a Textbox on the form, go to the properties, open the "Data" section and click the dropdown for the "Text" property. However the BindingSource we put on the form does not show as something we can bind to.

We want to use BindingSource's on the Form not at the project level.
All the website we have looked at use either a Project level BindingSource or Create the Bindingsource at runtime in code and then crete the bindings for the controls in code.

Question:
Do we have the correct usage of the components? (ie A TextBox or other control is bound to a Bindingsource and the BindingSource is bound to a DataSource) 
If this is not correct, what is the correct method for binding data  at design time.

If the issue is because the dataset does not have any data defined at design time, then we have tried deriving a custom class from BindingSource and implementing the IComponent interface to be used as the DataSource for the BindingSource.  In this case, when we try to drop the custom component on the form we get the following:
[Error when dropping custom component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddLfE.jpg)

However, our class has a constructor that takes no parameters, it also has one that takes an IContainer as a parameter:

```
public class CCSItemBase : BindingSource, IComponent
{
    public CCSItemBase()
    {
    }
    public CCSItemBase(IContainer Container):base(Container)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "We put a BindingSource on the form and set its DataSource to the DataSet." - But did you also set the `BindingSource.DataMember` property so that the `BindingSource` knows which `Table` in the `DataSet` to use?

Comment: When we drop open the member list, it lists nothing.  I am assuming this is because the dataset has no data defined (Since it will be filled in at runtime).

Comment: I think I understand now, you are adding an untyped (empty) `DataSet` to the form and using that as the `DataSource` for the `BindingSource`.  Is there a reason why you can not create a typed `DataSet` (View Menu>Other Windows>Data Sources) based on database tables you intend to use and then add an instance of that to the form?

Comment: We intend to use "Business" objects as the source of our data, which run queries against that database and provide the data as a list of objects with properties for the fields plus derived values that might come from other sources. That means we are not reading directly from the database